# Necesito crear un excel y comprimirlo en un zip

Tags: php, excel, zip

**buen día, necesito crear un excel y comprimirlo en un zip con php , ya que hago el excel pero no se como meterlo al zip ,antes que se descargue el excel ayuda por favor, supongamos que este es mi archivo y ahi tengo mi diseño de tabla en html , la idea es generarlo pero podermo almacenar temporalmente antes que se descargue para meterlo en un zip con otros archivos , **

```
`   header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-type:application/xls; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=usuarios.xls');


require_once('conexion.php');
$conn=new Conexion();
$link = $conn->conectarse();
/*$idtipofinanciamiento=$_GET['idtipofinan'];*/
$idtipofinanciamiento="1";
$idTipotrabajador="3";
$idestado="1";
$idEmpleado="";
$idEmpresa=1;




//"1","3","1","",1
//IdTipoFinanciamiento text,idTipotrabajador text,idestado text ,idEmpleado text,idEmpresa int

$strQry="call rptprocedimiento('".$idtipofinanciamiento."','".$idTipotrabajador."','".$idestado."','".$idEmpleado."',$idEmpresa)";


        $result=mysqli_query($link, $strQry);

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[]=$row;

            }





?>





 <TABLE border>
    <TR>
        <TD><img height="50" width="50" src="http://localhost/Exportaraexcel/imagenes/3-0001.jpg" alt="500" /></TD>
        <TD colspan=16 style="text-align: center;">

            COLEGIO DE EDUCACIÓN PROFESIONAL TÉCNICA DEL ESTADO DE QUERÉTARO<br>
            Reporte de Incidencias<br>
            RCQ-108

        </TD>
        <TD><img height="50" width="50" src="http://localhost/Exportaraexcel/imagenes/3-0001.jpg" alt="500" /></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD></TD> <TD></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: ¿Que haz intentado? lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Primeramente construyo mi excel con código HTML  hago una tabla en dónde va todo , en mi header content pongo que es un xls y al recargar pues me lo descarga en un excel

Comment: Es más fácil si añades el código en tu pregunta. ¿Estás utilizando librerías de terceros como: php-zip o PhpSpreadsheet?

Comment: por el momento no uso librerias , pense en solo colocarle las cabezeras y el codigo html y me lo decarga en excel , pero necesito ponerlo en un zip